# SQL Count function - simple aggregate needed

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

Consider the 2 columns below.

How can I add the count of each name and place it on each row, as per the 2nd table below?

```
name     amount
joe      5 
joe      6
joe      7
jim      3
jim      4
```

to

```
name  name_count   amount
joe    3           5
joe    3           6
joe    3           7
jim    2           3
jim    2           4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `COUNT(*)` function used with a windows clause.  This does an aggregation for each row -- but the rows are not reduced to a single row.

```
select name, count(*) over (partition by name) as name_count, amount
from table t;
```

This is ANSI standard functionality supported by most, but not all databases.  (As I write this, your question does not have a specific database tag.)

Comment: Sorry, it's for Oracle